# Dynamic multiple domains in one project

Tags: php, dns

I searched stackoverflow and google before posting this question.

I am developing a `PHP/MySQL` based dynamic conference website. Where users can register and create their own events for conference. Currently I have unique URL for each event and used `.htaccess` for that.

For example:

http://www.mydomain.com/event_name_1

http://www.mydomain.com/event_name_2

http://www.mydomain.com/event_name_3

**Problem:**

Now I want to change above implementations. Instead of using mydomain.com in URL I want to give users a feature where they can enter their own domain while using same code and database available on my server.

For example:

http://www.myclientdomain.com should run http://www.mydomain.com/client_event_name

I am not looking for code examples, I need directions what are possible options, is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://serverfault.com/a/519827/176761

> You're not trying to do anything too special, and it's definitely
>   possible. The way in which this is generally achieved is as follows:
>
> You configure a subdomain which is designed for receiving visitors
>   redirected from an external domain. For example,
>   `external.mydomain.com`. The page on the end of this will look at the
>   headers and query the database to decide where to redirect to. If a
>   user attempt to access directly, the page should return a 404, another
>   error or redirect to your home page.
>
> The user configures their domain (or subdomain, whatever) with a new
>   `CNAME` record of `external.mydomain.com`
>
> And finally, to prevent account hijacking, your service will normally
>   generate some kind of verification code which the user adds as a `TXT`
>   record.
>
> This is exactly how Google do it for Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions:

- Client's domain - hosted on your server.
- Each client's domain is linked to directory - where your php application is placed.
- Your application shows content depending on `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` value - which returns domain of your application (this would be in your case http://www.myclientdomain.com)

Comment: Please elaborate "Client's domain - hosted on your server. "

Comment: In your example: www.myclientdomain.com would be redirected to server where is your application stored (www.myclientdomain.com IN CNAME www.mydomain.com)

Comment: Redirect will change URL from www.myclientdomain.com to www.mydomain.com, I want user to navigate site with www.myclientdomain.com not with www.mydomain.com

Comment: And my clients are not technical, they don't know how to make their domain redirect to my domain.

Comment: 1. The way I described it above will not change client's domain to your. 2. It is not possible to use client's domain in your application without managing client's DNS.

Comment: That's what i am asking, is there any way or API to dynamically handle DNS?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to have access to customer's domain. Many domain registraars provides API to manage DNS. E.g. OVH - but you have to have login and password. Would be nice if all of your client's will have domains at the same registraar :-)

Comment: Thanx robson for help. Can you please guide me with the terms to search for API, as you said OVH also provide such API.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32659/discussion-between-irfan-danish-and-robson)